# AsciiDoc syntax highlighting plugin for Kate?

Tags: kate, syntax-highlighting, asciidoc

I'm looking for a way to add [AsciiDoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/) syntax highlighting to the Kate editor. I haven't found anything yet, but I feel sure some solution exists because AsciiDoc appears to be very popular (and is even used by O'Reilly publishing).

There are AsciiDoc syntax highlighters for Vim, GEdit, Emacs, TextMate, Geany and others. Surely Kate has one...

Comment: Someone attempted here: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274289, you might adapt or write your own: http://kate-editor.org/2005/03/24/writing-a-syntax-highlighting-file This might help as well: http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.text.formats.asciidoc/month=20130301

Comment: @Ketan hmmm thanks. But that sounds like bad news for me and other Kate lovers. I'm just learning AsciiDoc. Attempting to write my own syntax highlighting file is way beyond the scope of the project I'm working on (and I don't even think I *could* do it if I had time, given that bug report).